# Calculate similarity between list of words

Tags: python, data-mining, text-mining, similarity

I want to calculate the similarity between two list of words, for example :

`['email','user','this','email','address','customer']`

is similar to this list:

`['email','mail','address','netmail']`

I want to have a higher percentage of similarity than another list, for example:
`['address','ip','network']` even if **`address`** exists in the list.

Comment: What is your desired output for this?

Comment: percent of similarity for exemple 80% or more

Comment: Have you looked for cosine similarity?

Comment: For each word or the list of words?

Comment: For example two words are of 100% match, 1 almost 80-90 and the rest do not, what should be the output?

Comment: Yes, but i think cosine similarity give only the percent of similarity between two list, for exemple ['banana','appel','kiwi',....] compare to [banana','appel] the result using cosine similarity not 100% because the seconde list mising some items, i don't know how to have a high percent of similarity using cosine similarity even if the secon list miss some items

Comment: You can also compare words in cosine similarity. Again, in your case, what should be the output and why?

Comment: for exemple ['banana';'appel','steak'] compare to ['banan','appel','kiwi'...etc fruit] i want to have a high percent of similarity, compared to the others lists because the list ['banana';'appel','steak'] contain 2 item in the list  ['banana','appel','kiwi'...etc fruit]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Since you haven't really been able to demonstrate a crystal output, here is my best shot:

```
list_A = ['email','user','this','email','address','customer']
list_B = ['email','mail','address','netmail']
```

In the above two list, we will find the cosine similarity between each element of the list with the rest. i.e. `email` from `list_B` with every element in `list_A`:

```
def word2vec(word):
    from collections import Counter
    from math import sqrt

    # count the characters in word
    cw = Counter(word)
    # precomputes a set of the different characters
    sw = set(cw)
    # precomputes the "length" of the word vector
    lw = sqrt(sum(c*c for c in cw.values()))

    # return a tuple
    return cw, sw, lw

def cosdis(v1, v2):
    # which characters are common to the two words?
    common = v1[1].intersection(v2[1])
    # by definition of cosine distance we have
    return sum(v1[0][ch]*v2[0][ch] for ch in common)/v1[2]/v2[2]


list_A = ['email','user','this','email','address','customer']
list_B = ['email','mail','address','netmail']

threshold = 0.80     # if needed
for key in list_A:
    for word in list_B:
        try:
            # print(key)
            # print(word)
            res = cosdis(word2vec(word), word2vec(key))
            # print(res)
            print("The cosine similarity between : {} and : {} is: {}".format(word, key, res*100))
            # if res > threshold:
            #     print("Found a word with cosine distance > 80 : {} with original word: {}".format(word, key))
        except IndexError:
            pass
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
The cosine similarity between : email and : email is: 100.0
The cosine similarity between : mail and : email is: 89.44271909999159
The cosine similarity between : address and : email is: 26.967994498529684
The cosine similarity between : netmail and : email is: 84.51542547285166
The cosine similarity between : email and : user is: 22.360679774997898
The cosine similarity between : mail and : user is: 0.0
The cosine similarity between : address and : user is: 60.30226891555272
The cosine similarity between : netmail and : user is: 18.89822365046136
The cosine similarity between : email and : this is: 22.360679774997898
The cosine similarity between : mail and : this is: 25.0
The cosine similarity between : address and : this is: 30.15113445777636
The cosine similarity between : netmail and : this is: 37.79644730092272
The cosine similarity between : email and : email is: 100.0
The cosine similarity between : mail and : email is: 89.44271909999159
The cosine similarity between : address and : email is: 26.967994498529684
The cosine similarity between : netmail and : email is: 84.51542547285166
The cosine similarity between : email and : address is: 26.967994498529684
The cosine similarity between : mail and : address is: 15.07556722888818
The cosine similarity between : address and : address is: 100.0
The cosine similarity between : netmail and : address is: 22.79211529192759
The cosine similarity between : email and : customer is: 31.62277660168379
The cosine similarity between : mail and : customer is: 17.677669529663685
The cosine similarity between : address and : customer is: 42.640143271122085
The cosine similarity between : netmail and : customer is: 40.08918628686365
```

> Note: I have also commented the `threshold` part in the code, in case
>   you only want the words if their similarity exceeds a certain
>   threshold i.e. 80%

**EDIT**:

**OP**:  *but what i want exactly to do in not the comparaison word by word but, list by list*

Using `Counter` and `math`:

```
from collections import Counter
import math

counterA = Counter(list_A)
counterB = Counter(list_B)


def counter_cosine_similarity(c1, c2):
    terms = set(c1).union(c2)
    dotprod = sum(c1.get(k, 0) * c2.get(k, 0) for k in terms)
    magA = math.sqrt(sum(c1.get(k, 0)**2 for k in terms))
    magB = math.sqrt(sum(c2.get(k, 0)**2 for k in terms))
    return dotprod / (magA * magB)

print(counter_cosine_similarity(counterA, counterB) * 100)
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
53.03300858899106
```

Comment: Thanks you for your solution, but what i want exactly to do in not the comparaison word by word but, list by list : ['email','mail','address','netmail'] compare to  ['email','user','this','email','address','customer'] is more semilar (the percent is very high, the output should be 90% or more because the majority of words that exists in first list also exist in the second list), on the other hand  ['email','mail','address','netmail']  compare to ['address','ip','network'] the output is low percent even if address exist in the second list (the percent is relative to the others lists)

Comment: @YounessDrissiSlimani by high what do you mean, should we consider only the 100% match words? by then we can calculate how many words were a 100% from both list and then perhaps give an est percentage?

Comment: @YounessDrissiSlimani Great you may accept the answer if it helped: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work cheers

Comment: Hello @DirtyBit, i have a problem i try to compare vocab=['address','ip'] with two lists list_1 = "identifiant adresse ip address fixe horadatee cookie mac".split() list_2="address ville".split() the score is not exactly correct for me, what i want to have the consine similarity between list_1 and vocab is higher = 100% because all the items in vocab equal to some items in list_1.

Comment: @YounessDrissiSlimani I cannot be much of help like that, Please ask a new question with elaborated details that you have already and your attempts.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55398968/is-there-any-solution-to-get-score-of-similarity-between-lists-of-words   @DirtyBit

Answer (score 5):

You can leverage the power of Scikit-Learn (or other NLP) libraries to accomplish this. The example below uses CountVectorizer, but for more sophisticated analysis of documents it might be preferable to use the TFIDF vectorizer instead.

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer, TfidfVectorizer
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import cosine_similarity

def vect_cos(vect, test_list):
    """ Vectorise text and compute the cosine similarity """
    query_0 = vect.transform([' '.join(vect.get_feature_names())])
    query_1 = vect.transform(test_list)
    cos_sim = cosine_similarity(query_0.A, query_1.A)  # displays the resulting matrix
    return query_1, np.round(cos_sim.squeeze(), 3)

# Train the vectorizer
vocab=['email','user','this','email','address','customer']
vectoriser = CountVectorizer().fit(vocab)
vectoriser.vocabulary_ # show the word-matrix position pairs

# Analyse  list_1
list_1 = ['email','mail','address','netmail']
list_1_vect, list_1_cos = vect_cos(vectoriser, [' '.join(list_1)])

# Analyse list_2
list_2 = ['address','ip','network']
list_2_vect, list_2_cos = vect_cos(vectoriser, [' '.join(list_2)])

print('\nThe cosine similarity for the first list is {}.'.format(list_1_cos))
print('\nThe cosine similarity for the second list is {}.'.format(list_2_cos))
```

Output

```
The cosine similarity for the first list is 0.632.

The cosine similarity for the second list is 0.447.
```

## Edit

If you want to calculate the cosine similarity between "e-mail" and any other list of strings, train the vectoriser with "e-mail" and then analyse other documents.

```
# Train the vectorizer
vocab=['email']
vectoriser = CountVectorizer().fit(vocab)

# Analyse  list_1
list_1 =['email','mail','address','netmail']
list_1_vect, list_1_cos = vect_cos(vectoriser, [' '.join(list_1)])
print('\nThe cosine similarity for the first list is {}.'.format(list_1_cos))
```

Output

```
The cosine similarity for the first list is 1.0.
```

Comment: Good solution but if i train ['email','mail','address','netmail']  and i analyse ['email'] the output is 0.5, for me the correct answer is 0.99 or 1.0 because the weight of email is very high.

Comment: You clearly misunderstand how the code works. You have to train the vectoriser with vocabulary ['email] and then analyse ['email','mail','address','netmail'] with the vectoriser in order to get a cosine similarity of 1. See the updated code.

Comment: ah ok now i uderstand, it's possible to train ['email'] and when analyse ['user','mail'] it is similar because email is like mail. There is any possibility like to have vector of word ?

Comment: Could you clarify your last question, I don't understand it very well.

Comment: can i train ['email'] and when i test similarity with ['user','mail'] the output should be not 0.0 because email is equal to mail in the maining

Comment: hello @KRKirov, can i train vocab=['address'] and analyse list_1 = "ip address fixe mac cookie".split() list_2 = "code postal address city ville".split()  i want to have the percent of simliraty in list_2 higher than list_1 how i can do this, i tried to duplicate the word address in list_2 to have a good score for this word but it's not working.

Comment: When you train the vectoriser with a single "word", the analysis of any subsequent list of strings is equivalent to a binary outcome between: "The list contains the word" - outcome 1, "The list does not contain the word" - outcome 0. Therefore, no matter how long your list is, the cosine similarity between the list and the "word" is 1. Essentially, you are projecting the list onto the "word" vector, and if the word is in the list you are comparing the "word" with itself.

Comment: On the other hand if you train your vectoriser with list_1 and then analyze list_1 and list_2, the cosine similarities are 1 and 0.45, respectively.

Answer (score 0):

I'm suggesting this answer because the title of the question may bring people here looking to solve a related but different problem. If you only care about whether the words are present or absent, then one approach is [Jaccard similarity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jaccard_index). Although this can be found in a number of toolkits, it's also very easy to compute directly in Python:

```
def jaccard(list1, list2):
    s1 = set(list1)
    s2 = set(list2)
    u = s1 | s2
    if u:
        return float(len(s1 & s2))/float(len(u))
    else:
        return 0.0

list_A = ['email','user','this','email','address','customer']
list_B = ['email','mail','address','netmail']
list_C = ['address','ip','network']
jaccard(list_A, list_B)
jaccard(list_A, list_C)
```

Output

```
0.2857142857142857
0.14285714285714285
```

The result if the sets are both empty isn't actually defined for Jaccard, so this checks for that and says they are not similar if they're both empty, but you could also say that makes them perfectly similar (1.0). You can decide if you want to convert these values (0-1) into percentages on printout.

Neither of them returns anything close to 80%, but that's because this approach is only looking for the words to match exactly, and not looking for "near matches" like "email", "mail", and "netmail". For that you need something like nltk, for example [nltk.corpus.reader.wordnet](https://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.corpus.reader.wordnet.html). It's also insensitive to the fact that 'email' appears twice in `list_A`, but then I don't think it is clear from the question how that is *supposed* to be treated: when it appears twice in A and only once in B, does that *increase* the similarity (because there are multiple matching pairs) or *decrease* the similarity (because you want to word frequencies to be similar between the sets)?