# Cosine Similarity between two lists using word2vec / wordnet

Tags: python, word2vec, similarity, wordnet, cosine-similarity

It's possible to get the averge of similarity between two lists of words using word2vec pretrained model (GoogleNews-vectors-negative300) or wordnet :

```
dic_email=['email','e-mail','address'] # dictionary of email contain word similar to email
dic_identity=['name','first','last','identity','forename']
lista = ['fullname','user'] # fullname is similar to name 
listb = ['phone','number']
resa=lista.compare(dic_email,dic_identity) #just an example of my function compare
restb=listb.compare(dic_email,dic_identity)

print('the percent of similarity is :'+resa)
print('the percent of similarity is :'+resb)
```

> Result should be :

```
the percent of similarity is : [('dic_identity',0.8),('dic_email',0.0)] # i just gives a rondom percent to explain lista is similar to dic_identity beacause fullname is similar to the item in dic_identity  
the percent of similarity is : [('dic_identity',0.0),('dic_email',0.0)]
```

Comment: How do you indent do define cosine similarity between two lists ? Do you intend to define it as the mean of the cosine similarity between all the pairs in the two lists ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calculate similarity between list of words](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55162668/calculate-similarity-between-list-of-words)

Comment: @mujjiga yes for example in dic_identity there is a item name, forname is similar to fullname if we use model.most_similar from gensim we get a high percent which mean there is similar.

Comment: Are you asking how to implement a `compare()` function which does this? If so, it's not clear how the **three** different lists-of-words in one of your example operations like `lista.compare(dic_email,dic_identity)` – `lista`, `dic_email`, `dic_identity` – are supposed to be compared. (Do you just want 2 of them compared? Or does the 3rd somehow filter the desired comparison? Are some of those lists supposed to be key->value dicts?)

Comment: Note that a Python function like `compare()` will *not* know the outer-context variable names passed-in (like `dic_identity`), just the values, so it couldn't include those names in a tabular return value (unless by coincidence it was hard-wired to know those names, perhaps because they happen to match the parameter-variable names). Also, cosine-similarity shouldn't really be interpreted as a percentage. (It can be negative, and its magnitude/distribution doesn't really correspond to an "amount of overlap".)