# Finding similarities and contradictor statements in strings with Python

Tags: python, nlp, nltk

I want to write code that will find similarities between strings. I found this script on StackOverflow, and it words good, but the problem is that I want to find contradictor statements. I have no idea how to do this, so im asking for help

```
from difflib import SequenceMatcher


def similar(a, b):
    return SequenceMatcher(None, a, b).ratio()


x = similar("sky is blue","color of the sky is blue")
print(x)
0.6285714285714286

x = similar("sky is blue","color of the sky is not blue")
print(x)
0.5641025641025641

x = similar("people are telling that sky is blue","people are telling that is not blue")
print(x)
0.8857142857142857
```

You see that I get 0.88 score for two contradictor statements, so that score should be much less, or it should return some kind of label (true or fake, contradict or something like that)

My inputs are text inputs, sentances (3-15 words). Something like fact - checking

Comment: It will be good if you add expected output.

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55162668/calculate-similarity-between-list-of-words/55163071#55163071

Comment: @OlvinRoght I have added expected output

Comment: This is not as trivial as it seems. Most similarity measures are statistical ones based on vectors and bag of word models. Therefore, they are insensitive to small negation markers like "not". The solution to this task highly depends on the structural variability of your input data. Could you give more precise info on your input and the exact text type?  On a free text corpus, e.g. Wikipedia, this might be impossible without deeper analysis of syntax.

Comment: @CLpragmatics My inputs are lowercase text inputs, sentences (3-15 words). Something like fact - checking

Answer (score 0):

try to use Sentence Embedding , it convert the sentences to vectors [20 65 32 ...] then use them to calculate the similarity.

Sentence embedding depend on word embedding which convert each word in the sentence to vector then take the SUM or AVG as you need

-> how to do word embedding ?
you have 2 choices , first of them is to use pre-trained model of word2vec like Google's model but it's too much space for u 1.5GB!!! but it will give you incredible results

the second choice is to build your own model

here you will find the code to use Google's pre-trained model and the sentence embedding function
https://www.kaggle.com/esraaibrahim22/sentiment-analysis-using-google-s-trained-word2vec