# pandas: group near similar string data

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, similarity

I am trying to use groupby on a column with `str` type of data that has near similar values and get a count of it:

for example:

```
col A   col year   col C

abc    2009      no plan today
abc2   2009     wrong plan today
```

I'd like to get a count of 2 in this case.

I thought of something like:

`df.groupby(['col year', 'col C'], as_index = False)`

but this would not work considering there's a differnce in the col C values as well. What could possibly be an elegant way of handling this?

I saw an answer with cosine similarity here: [Calculate similarity between list of words](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55162668/calculate-similarity-between-list-of-words/55163071#55163071)

and perhaps this could be used somehow?

Comment: You need to define "near similar", change column values based on that, and then unify them. Then your groupby works as desired.

Answer (score 0):

I will point you to the right direction, but will keep the actual implementation to you.

You can use the Levenshtein distance. There is a python package for this that gets as an input 2 strings and returns a number of how "close" those strings are. Simple as that:

```
from Levenshtein import distance

text_distance = distance(text_1, text_2)
```

Then what you can do is, you iterate over the rows of the DataFrame and for each row, you check if the Levenshtein distance between the current text value and the text column of any previously group is less than a given threshold. If it is, the row is appended to that group, if not, a new group is created with the current row as the first member of the group.

The threshold is something you need to experiment and understand what value will give you the best results.